# Match only the first set of numbers in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to retrieve the first set of numbers from a string, but I'm not sure how.

I have the following, which I was expecting to pick each set of numbers so that I could then pick the first key from the `$matches` array, but it literally matches only the first number.

In this example I'd be looking for '123'. Can someone please let me know how to do this with RegEx (or a better way if RegEx is not best for the job). Thanks.

```
$e = 'abc 123,456,def, 789-ab-552'; // Just a random example
$pattern = "/[0-9]/";
preg_match($pattern, $e, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add a quantifier:

```
$pattern = "/[0-9]+/";
```

`+` means *one or more*

You can find an ajax regex tester for php [here](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) and more informations about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).